# Stop Javascript function if it's freeze to long

Tags: javascript, timeout, intervals

I've got

`function doSome(){}`

What should I do if I want stop execution of this function when it's executing more then 200 mills?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could to it internally in function.

Comment: You cannot. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded)

Comment: Move your function to a web worker

Comment: I love it when people say "you can't" when you can. To put it simply, you should make the function responsible for terminating itself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess 200 milliseconds it's a little to short, but:

- if you have a while loop, create a `Date` object before entering the loop and a new one in the loop. If the difference is greater than 200, break it

  ```
  start = new Date()
  while (1) {
      end = new Date()
      if (end - start > 200) break
      // work
  {
  ```
- If you're executing Ajax call, see [aborting AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

A [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) can be terminated with its [`terminate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Terminating_a_worker) function. There is no other way to interrupt execution of Javascript from within Javascript itself. Note that many browsers also have slow script detection which prompts the user when a script runs a certain amount of time or number of instructions. This is not controllable from Javascript, however.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of algorithm that is implemented within the function, you could check how long it's been running, but it isin't very precise and you would have to make sure that each loop iteration takes very little time to process.

For instance:

```
function doSomething() {
    var startTime = new Date.now(),
        i = -1,
        itemsToProcess = [1, 2, 3, 4],
        len = itemsToProcess.length;

    while ((Date.now() - startTime) <= 200 && ++i < len) {
        //process items here
    }
}
```

You could also avoid the freezing by giving the browser some time to breath using
`setTimeout` or `setInterval`. That is probably a better approach if you want to task to always complete.

```
function startDoSomething(items, delay) {
    var i = arguments[2] || 0;

    //process
    console.log('processing item at: ' + i);

    if (++i < items.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            startDoSomething(items, delay, i);
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

Finally, a much more efficient way to handle long-running processes would be to use a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers), you can't **directly** update the DOM from the worker.